# Point in polygon hit test algorithm

Tags: clipperlib

I need to test if a point hits a polygon with holes and isles. I'd like to understand how I'm *supposed* to do this. That's not documented and I can't find any explanation or examples.

What I do is count `+1` for every *outer polygon* hit and `-1` for every *inner polygon* hit. The resulting sum is:

- > 0: hit;
- <= 0: miss (outside or in a hole).

The `HitData` class separates *paths* based on winding number to avoid unnecessary recomputation of `orientation`. With `Clipper.PointInPolygon()` applied to every *path* the sum is easy to compute.

But there are two major drawbacks:

1. I have to apply `Clipper.PointInPolygon()` to **EVERY** *path*;
2. I can't leverage the hierarchy of `PolyTree`.

Can someone who has hands-on experience with Clipper ([@angus-johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359538/angus-johnson)?) clear up this confusion?

Again, my question is: **how am I supposed to implement this**? Am I re-inventing the wheel, while there's an actual solution readily available in the Clipper Library?

> Side note: `PolyTree` still requires to test **EVERY** *path* to determine which `PolyNode` the point is in. There's no `Clipper.PointInPolyTree()` method and, thus, AFAIK `PolyTree` doesn't help.

The structure that separates outer and inner polygons:

```
public class HitData
{
    public List<List<IntPoint>> Outer, Inner;

    public HitData(List<List<IntPoint>> paths)
    {
        Outer = new List<List<IntPoint>>();
        Inner = new List<List<IntPoint>>();

        foreach (List<IntPoint> path in paths)
        {
            if (Clipper.Orientation(path))
            {
                Outer.Add(path);
            } else {
                Inner.Add(path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the algorithm that tests a point:

```
public static bool IsHit(HitData data, IntPoint point)
{
    int hits;

    hits = 0;

    foreach (List<IntPoint> path in data.Outer)
    {
        if (Clipper.PointInPolygon(point, path) != 0)
        {
            hits++;
        }
    }

    foreach (List<IntPoint> path in data.Inner)
    {
        if (Clipper.PointInPolygon(point, path) != 0)
        {
            hits--;
        }
    }

    return hits > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone who has hands-on experience with Clipper (@angus-johnson?) clear up this confusion?

It's not clear to me what your confusion is. As you've correctly observed, the Clipper library does not provide a function to determine whether a point is inside multiple paths.

**Edit (13 Sept 2019):**

OK, I've now created a `PointInPaths` function (in Delphi Pascal) that determines whether a point is inside multiple paths. Note that this function accommodates the different polygon filling rules.

```
function CrossProduct(const pt1, pt2, pt3: TPointD): double;
var
  x1,x2,y1,y2: double;
begin
  x1 := pt2.X - pt1.X;
  y1 := pt2.Y - pt1.Y;
  x2 := pt3.X - pt2.X;
  y2 := pt3.Y - pt2.Y;
  result := (x1 * y2 - y1 * x2);
end;


function PointInPathsWindingCount(const pt: TPointD;
  const paths: TArrayOfArrayOfPointD): integer;
var
  i,j, len: integer;
  p: TArrayOfPointD;
  prevPt: TPointD;
  isAbove: Boolean;
  crossProd: double;
begin
  //nb: returns MaxInt ((2^32)-1) when pt is on a line
  Result := 0;
  for i := 0 to High(paths) do
  begin
    j := 0;
    p := paths[i];
    len := Length(p);
    if len < 3 then Continue;
    prevPt := p[len-1];
    while (j < len) and (p[j].Y = prevPt.Y) do inc(j);
    if j = len then continue;
    isAbove := (prevPt.Y < pt.Y);
    while (j < len) do
    begin
      if isAbove then
      begin
        while (j < len) and (p[j].Y < pt.Y) do inc(j);
        if j = len then break
        else if j > 0 then prevPt := p[j -1];
        crossProd := CrossProduct(prevPt, p[j], pt);
        if crossProd = 0 then
        begin
          result := MaxInt;
          Exit;
        end
        else if crossProd < 0 then dec(Result);
      end else
      begin
        while (j < len) and (p[j].Y > pt.Y) do inc(j);
        if j = len then break
        else if j > 0 then prevPt := p[j -1];
        crossProd := CrossProduct(prevPt, p[j], pt);
        if crossProd = 0 then
        begin
          result := MaxInt;
          Exit;
        end
        else if crossProd > 0 then inc(Result);
      end;
      inc(j);
      isAbove := not isAbove;
    end;
  end;
end;

function PointInPaths(const pt: TPointD;
  const paths: TArrayOfArrayOfPointD; fillRule: TFillRule): Boolean;
var
  wc: integer;
begin
  wc := PointInPathsWindingCount(pt, paths);
  case fillRule of
    frEvenOdd: result := Odd(wc);
    frNonZero: result := (wc <> 0);
  end;
end;
```

**With regards leveraging the PolyTree structure:**
The top nodes in PolyTree are outer nodes that together contain every (nested) polygon. So you'll only need to perform `PointInPolygon` on these top nodes until a positive result is found. Then repeat `PointInPolygon` on that nodes nested paths (if any) looking for a positive match there. Obviously when an outer node fails `PointInPolygon` test, then its nested nodes (polygons) will also fail. Outer nodes will increment the winding count and inner holes will decrement the winding count.

Comment: Dear Dr. Johnson, your first solution is the same as the `IsHit()` method. That's ok and what I ended up using. I was just wondering if there was a faster algorithm. This one checks ALL nodes of the tree, while only one path would have sufficed. I hoped in some readily implemented code that could reduce the number of nodes checked. Maybe by starting from the bottom nodes and then moving upwards to the root? But quite some time has passed since I had this doubt and the "suboptimal" solution was good enough! Still, thank you for taking your time answering my question :)

Comment: @pid. Yes, you're right, my solution 1 is the same as your `IsHit()` function above (which evidently I didn't look at closely). Also, as to your statement: _"I can't leverage the hierarchy of PolyTree"_, I think PolyTree **can** be leveraged since you only need to check top level nodes for `PointInPolygon` and only drill down into their childs when `PointInPolygon` returns a positive result.

Comment: Also, regarding PolyTree, I wouldn't recommend forcing a clipping operation just to build a PolyTree structure, especially if you're concerned about performance. So unless you're post processing a clipping operation, I suspect Solution 2 will be the faster of the 2 solutions.

Comment: Great! I was just looking for this. Any chance you will add it to Clipper and release a new version?